# Rails 5: WebRTC video conferencing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html5-video, webrtc

After having seen [DHH's Rails 5 chat app demo](https://medium.com/@dhh/rails-5-action-cable-demo-8bba4ccfc55e#.f8qkqnqz0) I have the following question:

What elements would I need to add/implement additionally to use Rails 5's WebRTC functionality in order to set up a video conferencing app? (For instance, is it correct that Rails 5 already contains the required Signaling server, the STUN server and the TURN server? What additional libraries are required?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What elements would I need to add/implement additionally to use Rails 5's WebRTC functionality in order to set up a video conferencing app?

Rails 5 doesn't have any WebRTC functionality built in.

> For instance, is it correct that Rails 5 already contains the required Signaling server, the STUN server and the TURN server?

No. Rails 5 comes with a new library called [ActionCable](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable). ActionCable was created to integrate [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) in Rails apps, thats it.

You might be confused because WebSockets are often used as a signalling transport in WebRTC applications.

> What additional libraries are required?

I'd suggest reading [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/), which outlines the required architecture.

[image: The full Monty: STUN, TURN and signaling]